# Rails in depth plugin tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to learn rails plugins, in a very detailed way so I can understand how the rails plugins at github are designed.

I'm looking for something that goes over things at a high level, but then goes detailed.

```
plugins, generators, etc.
```

does this exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are really looking for is deep understanding of Ruby Object Model and Ruby Metaprogramming. Crystal clear understanding of both of them is critical to be able to build variety of useful rails plugins. I would not recommend diving head first into rails plugin development without these two.

Unfortunately, I don't have many resources that would give you deep insights in them but here is something to get you started.

http://www.hokstad.com/ruby-object-model.html

http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/Understanding%20Ruby%27s%20Object%20Model/ChrisPine_UROM.ppt

http://www.rubyfleebie.com/3-steps-to-understand-how-classes-and-objects-work-in-ruby/

Also, I highly recommend this book - [Ruby Metaprogramming by Dave Thomas](http://pragprog.com/screencasts/v-dtrubyom/the-ruby-object-model-and-metaprogramming) and also careful reading of [The Ruby Way](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672328844).

Once you are thorough with the object model and metaprogramming, understanding the design of rails becomes easier and with experience, it starts to come naturally. Extending the same with plugins and gems would whole lot easier as well.

Comment: nice, but what about walk through the plugins itself, all the callbacks and places that can be bind in plugins?

Comment: Again, you need to understand how ActiveRecord/ActionController is designed and how the callbacks/hooks work. Its again Ruby. Master Ruby first. That's my advise. I don't think there are any shortcuts when it comes to this.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html

Comment: that's not deep enough, i know of that one :)